# C: warning: format '%s' expects a matching 'char *' argument

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, printf

I'm currently working on File I/O and I tried using this function:

```
fprintf (FILE *pFile, char *pFormat, <variable list>);
```

with my variables

```
fprintf ( filePtr, "\"%s\"n", myarray );
```

My compiler issues a warning that says `warning: format '%s' expects a matching 'char *' argument` but I have declared `myarray` as `char *myarray = "This is a string"`. Can anyone tell me what went wrong? My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
FILE *filePtr;
char *myarray = "This is a string";

if ((filePtr = fopen("sample.dat", "w")) == NULL) {
   printf ("File could not be opened.\n");
} else {
   printf ("This will print the string onto file:\n");

   while (!feof(filePtr)) {
      fprintf ( filePtr, "\"%s\"", myarray );
   }
}
fclose (filePtr);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No. Show actual code.

Comment: why are you using backward slashes in the format string?

Comment: Show us the __actual__ code. And give us the full compiler output.

Comment: Krister, he's trying to print a string that's enclosed in (literal) double-quotes. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Note that you need to `fopen()` the file in write mode. Also that the `while` loop will never terminate. Use `feof()` to indicate the end of a file you're _reading_, not writing.

Comment: This code compiles fine for me under `gcc` on linux. Suggest you look for typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to compile with gcc, it found another issue - missing argument in the fopen:

```
 if ((filePtr = fopen("sample.dat")) == NULL) {
```

So, need to use:

```
 if ((filePtr = fopen("sample.dat", "r")) == NULL) {
```

Thereafter, code compiled without problem.
Compiler version:

```
gcc version 4.2.1 20070831 patched [FreeBSD]
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, I've tried compiling it in a different version and it compiled fine too. Thanks.